# How to assign the color to a button based on the value from firebase and change it on press on both firebase and on screen?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I want the background color of a *Pressable* preset to either blue or green based on the value present in firebase, i.e. if it is true in firebase, the color of the *Pressable* is green, else it is blue.

Also, if I press the button, it switches values in the firebase and also the color of the button swaps.

In my code, when I click the *Pressable*, the color changes and the value is swapped in firebase too, but it does not have the color preset when I load the application.

The button should have the color green the moment it loads if the value in firebase is true.

Here is my code.

```
import {StatusBar} from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Pressable, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app';
import {getDatabase, ref, onValue, set} from 'firebase/database';
import {color} from 'react-native-reanimated';

const firebaseConfig = {};
initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: this.readVals('value/'),
    };
  }

  readVals(path) {
    const db = getDatabase();
    const reference = ref(db, path);
    onValue(reference, (snapshot) => {
      const value = snapshot.val().obj;
      return value;
    });
  
  }

  setVals(path) {
      const db = getDatabase();
      const reference = ref(db, path);
      const val = this.state.l1;
      set(reference, {
        obj: !val
      });
      this.state.l1 = !val;
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Pressable
          style={({pressed}) => [
            {
              backgroundColor: this.state.value ? '#FF0000' : '#00FF00',
            },
            styles.button,
          ]} onPress={() => {this.setVals('value/')}}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Button</Text>
        </Pressable>

        <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#FF0000',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

  button: {
    flex: 0.15,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.25)',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginTop: 20,
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 20,
  },
});
```

Is it possible to have the background color preset?
Please let me know how.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the state only after you fetched the value like this:

```
this.state = {
      value: null;
   };


readVals(path) {
    const db = getDatabase();
    const reference = ref(db, path);
    onValue(reference, (snapshot) => {
      const value = snapshot.val().obj;
      this.setState({value: value});
    });
  }
```